# How can i disconnect from the DB when using sqlplus in emacs?

Tags: sql, oracle, emacs, sqlplus

I'm trying to use sqlplus in Emacs. It works fine. But I don't know how I can disconnect from the DB once I started the sqlplus session.

I'm using sqlplus mode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlPlusMode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `EXIT;` and hit return. It should disconnect you from the DB and close the SQLPlus.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Emacs sqlplus mode, but, in SQL*Plus, you can simply type 'disconnect' if you want to disconnect the current session without exiting SQL*Plus.